# Select all td in tr in nested table with css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I want to select all td inside the first tr of the tbody. I would normally do this like: tbody:first-child td --> but this gives me the result you can see on the image, the yellow is the result.

[image]

### My html - short version

I know there are unclosed tags but i copied this from my debugger because everything is generated by jquery. Any ideas?

```
   <table class="wc-header">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3">Medewerker 1</td>
                <td class="row_header">Van</td>
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="1" data-row="from">
                <input class="past selected" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                </td>
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="2" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="3" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="4" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="5" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="6" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="7" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="8" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours wc-today" data-person="1" data-day="9" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="10" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="11" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="12" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="13" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="14" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="15" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="16" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="17" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="18" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="19" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="20" data-row="from">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="21" data-row="from">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="row_header">Tot</td>
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="1" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="2" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="3" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="4" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="5" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="6" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="7" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="8" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours wc-today" data-person="1" data-day="9" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="10" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="11" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="12" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="13" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="14" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="15" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="16" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="17" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="18" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours" data-person="1" data-day="19" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="20" data-row="till">
                <td class="hours specialday" data-person="1" data-day="21" data-row="till">
            </tr>
        <tr>
        </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

### EDIT

Maybe I should explain what i'm actually trying to do.  The black line you see on the left is a border given to the TBODY. I want this line having the width of the table, but the border gets overriden by the border of the td's. Maybe any other solutions?

### CSS

```
[data-person] {
    border:1px solid #DEDEDE;
}


tbody tr:first-child td {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

### Solved

I had an override problem with the td's. Realized this after I posted my question, thx for help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclosed `td`, `tr`, `thead` and `tbody` tags aren't a problem - don't worry. But I see multiple `tbody`s - do you want to select the first row in the first `tbody` only, or any first row?

Comment: any first row in every tbody. One tbody is one big row as you can see in the image with in columnheader "Medewerker"

Comment: Can you add classes to the jQuery output?

Comment: Yes, but that's the last option i was considering... If nobody can give me an easier way, i will add classes. Thx for the respond btw guys

Comment: The problem is the styles get overriden. Any idea how i can make sure this particular style gets priority over the others? !important doesn't work. Specifying classes and id's ext i have done already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
tbody tr:first-child td {/* your styles */}
```

### Demo

Comment: Works in the demo I provided. You could have other styles interfering with that on your actual page.

Comment: Yes, i guess that's the problem. I added an edit, maybe you got any idea how can solve the override of the border?

Comment: For a test, simply add `!important` to the defined styles in the selector I wrote for you.

Comment: !important doesn't work. Specifying classes and id's ext i have done already... Still not solved

Comment: This is a snippet of your code and the actual css is not in your question's context. For your provided snippet the provided solution works. I guess you have to do some debugging on your end to get it done on your actual code. The good thing is that you have the correct selector for the elements you want to target.

Comment: Yes it does, didn't realize it was an overrideproblem at first. That's why i added some edits.

Comment: as you said you solved the question I asked, and in the mean time i found my override problem. Thx 4 the help

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to be of help to you. You can mark the answer as the Answer for future reference.